# How to write jenkins pipeline for Jira Release Version parameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jira, pipeline

I have freestyle Jenkins job with Jira Release Version Parameter:

[image]

I need to migrate this job to use Jenkins pipeline instead of freestyle job. Can somebody give me a piece of pipeline code (in declarative language) which does that?

Comment: Does [Jira Steps](https://jenkinsci.github.io/jira-steps-plugin/) plugin help you?

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation, we figured out that at this moment it is not possible to implement this plugin in the pipeline job.

Comment: do you know if it is possible now?